# Cannot override Angular-material 2 css

Tags: css, angular-material2

I have an issue with a checkbox label when using Angular material 2 (https://material.angular.io/). If the label is too long (more than 1 line), the class `.mat-checkbox-layout {white-space: nowrap}` as default makes the label line goes beyond screen width. Therefore I tried to change it to `{white-space: normal !important}`, but it did not change anything. I tried also several approaches such as including `deep` or `::ng-deep` and set `ViewEncapsulation` to `none`, but still nothing changed.

[image]

Comment: Specify a (max-)width …?

Comment: no, that's not the way it should work, the `white-space: nowrap` is only the issue.